# How do you make a field always default to a value in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a text field (column).

Every time I create a record I want this particular column, called "type", to default to "FC" for every new record.

I can't get it to work.

[image]

Comment: As you can see below: please specify what you mean with "always". Do you just want this value when someone insers without a specific value, or do you want this value even is something else is specified?

Answer (score 1):

Try this after your create table statement:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY type columnType Default 'FC';
```

That way, every time you insert a new row, `type` will have the value 'FC' unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Sorry bout that, that was completely useless. I was cross-eyed? Anyway, this still won't help as you can insert a value that's not 'FC' for a new insert.

Comment: @Nanne: Isn't a "default" just a specified value that is provided when there is no other value provided? I was under the impression that if you wanted to, you could have type as something else...

Comment: If you insert with the colum `type` and give it value `"thisisnotFC", you can. So the question is what the OP means with **always**. Is it "I just want a default value", or is it "No matter how the insert is, the default must ALWAYS be set". ANd in that case it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Is your query inserting that column as a blank value? if so, that is probably the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only sollution I can think of is a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

A quick untested example from the manual and from the top of my head:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER ins_yourtable AFTER INSERT ON yourtable
->FOR EACH ROW SET type = 'FC';
```

---

If you can control all inserts you can also just skip the column while inserting: they you'll get the default value. But when the value is filled with someting (even '') it will get that value, so you're not forcing it.